# CSS infinite animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

This project I am working on required me to build a moving animation that uses nothing other than css and styled divs.

A perfect working example of something almost identical can be found here (note the blue background white moving squares):

http://www.braintreepayments.com

However, unlike the demo above, my design consists of about 10 times more div shapes in the animation and when the animation timing expires, the container becomes blank, which makes it looks like it was poorly designed.

My question is, how does the animation in the above example create the 'continuous / infinite effect' on their website, with so little styled divs? I have been trying to formulate something to replicate this effect no success.

Note: I open to using a JQuery / Javascript solution as well.

Comment: In their code: `.animated-marquee-container {
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;`

Comment: By using the [`anitmation-iteration-count`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-iteration-count-property) property and using the `infinite` value - you will have a hard time finding the matching selector as their CSS is minified, but that rule exists in their stylesheet.

Comment: Can you put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Adrift, thank you! I figured it out :) You're right this does create an infinite effect, very interesting :D Please repost your commend so I can select it as a solution.

Comment: Undeleted by your request (even though it's not much of an answer) :p - I'm glad you got it working ..

Comment: @Adrift! It is exactly what I needed, it addresses the question, and it is what I ended up using, it couldn't be any more of an answer and I am sure it will help other people out there with a similar problem ;) Thanks again, it ended up working great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [`anitmation-iteration-count`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-iteration-count-property) property and using the `infinite` value - you will have a hard time finding the matching selector as their CSS is minified, but that rule exists somewhere in their stylesheet.

Comment: It's `.animated-marquee-container { animation-iteration-count: infinite; }` if you're interested

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I am a bit lost, would `animation-iteration-count:infinite;` replace the currently used: `animation: animatedBackground 50s linear;` somehow?

Comment: No, but you could put just `animation: animatedBackground 50s linear infinite;`

Comment: It would if `animation-iteration-count: infinite;` was defined *before* the rule you posted - as that is the shorthand and the initial value is 1 for `animation-iteration-count` - it's likely defined after, though I don't see why they wouldn't include it in the shorthand.